# Run a SQL Query inside a loop and append the results one below other

Tags: sql, hive

I have a Hive - sql query that looks something like this structure,

```
Set my_date= '2019-02-28';

select * from table_a a where data_date = '${hiveconf:Required_Date}' 
         inner join table_b on a.id = b.id;
```

I want to run this query starting from 2019-02-28 to current months ending date.

Only one date of the month is required which is the last date of the month.

To be more precise, currently I am running it for 2019-02-28. I want to run the same query for 2019-03-31 and 2019-04-30, 2019-05-31.....2019-11-30.

If it is a programming language I would do a For loop and append one below other.

How do we do it with SQL.

Comment: I am querying it on Hive.

Comment: It is a long query and I don't want to change the values in multiple places. So, I am using a parameter and setting that up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, given that Hive doesn't seem to know what the "last date" of any given month is, you could create a 12 row table with the days you're interested in (the last day of each month), and then create a query which selects that date and joins it on table_a's data_date (or use an array with the last dates to avoid having to create the table):

```
select * from last_month_days lmd
inner join table_a a
on lmd.date = a.data_date
inner join table_b b
on a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work for what you are trying to achieve? It will join against table_b for all rows in table_a that have a date equal to the last day of a month.

```
select * from table_a a where date_date=LAST_DAY(data_date) 
                              and data_date>='2019-02-28'
         inner join table_b b on a.id = b.id;
```